# Using subscript character in C# code?

Tags: c#, .net

Considering that the C# compiler should be able to handle Unicode characters, I'm curious to know why the subscript character doesn't seem to work? It'd be nice to use it in conjunction with Linq, I think (pseudo-code):

```
collection.Sort((x₀, x₁) => x₁.CompareTo(x₀));
```

Comment: You could just use this instead: ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because subscript characters aren't in the allowed character classes, basically.

See [C# language specification, 2.4.2 Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx) for the rules. Digits in an identifier must be of the Unicode class "Nd", or "Number, decimal digit".

See [Unicode Character 'SUBSCRIPT ONE' (U+2081)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2081/index.htm) for the information on this particular character:

```
Category                    Number, Other [No]

Character.isDigit()         No
Character.isLetter()        No
Character.isLetterOrDigit() No
```

This also means that however you compare it, a subscript 1 != the digit 1.

Comment: Not to mention it takes more than one keystroke to type it in. Most programmers aren't confused by `x1` and `x2`.

Comment: @RonBeyer I know, and I use  _x0_, _x1_, ...  myself, but I still think it would've been a nice feature of the language if it worked.

Comment: @Zanathel I disagree just for the amount of keystrokes it takes to type in. Personally if its not on my keyboard, its not in my code. I have seen some strange unicode stuff in code files and it just makes it difficult, especially if using a non-standard editor, like Notepad.

Comment: @RonBeyer I'm not a proponent of adding support for these special characters to the language, but I'm merely curious as to why it doesn't work. _CodeCaster_ gave me the answer I sought.